# In pandas, split column into 2 based on appearance of +-

Tags: pandas, string, data-manipulation

We have

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'open': ['-2.5+2.5', '+3-3', '-1.5+1.5', '-1+1', '+3.5-3.5', 'PKPK']})
```

[image]

And we need to split this column to get:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'open1': ['-2.5', '+3', '-1.5', '-1', '+3.5', 'PK'],
    'open2': ['+2.5', '-3', '+1.5', '+1', '-3.5', 'PK']
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use lookahead `(?=\d)` and lookbehind `(?<=\d)` assertions. They do not consume characters after splitting. Add `[+-]` regular expression to lookahead and use `|` OR  to cover PKPK issues.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'open': ['-2.5+2.5', '+3-3', '-1.5+1.5', '-1+1', '+3.5-3.5', 'PKPK']})
df=df['open'].str.split('(?<=[\d]|K)(?=[+-]|P)', expand=True)
```

[image]

Comment: apologies for tweaking question but please see edit. noticed two issues (1) the 2nd +- is dropped, and (2) the PKPK is not split

Answer (score 1):

It works like that because you've given \d+ to your regex pattern and it will not work for float. For example when you have 2.5 - it takes 2 and then it sees a dot.

You could consider modifying the pattern to find both - float and integers:

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame({'open': ['-2.5+2.5', '+3-3', '-1.5+1.5', 
                                   '-1+1', '+3.5-3.5', 'PKPK']})

output_df['open'].str.extractall(r'([-+]?\d*\.\d+|[-+]?\d+|PK+)').unstack()
```

**Output:**

```
                0
match     0     1
    0  -2.5  +2.5
    1    +3    -3
    2  -1.5  +1.5
    3    -1    +1
    4  +3.5  -3.5
    5    PK    PK
```